# how to find control in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, controls

i want to access to my O1 control in my gridview
here is the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="SelectedPollGridView" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="PollID" DataSourceID="SelectedPollSqlDataSource" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <p class="text-center"><small><%#Eval("Header") %></small></p>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <p class="text-right"><%#Eval("Body") %></p>
                                <div  class="text-right">
                                    <div runat="server" id="O1Div" visible='<%#Eval("O1Vis") %>' class="radio ">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="pull-right" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="O1" value="option1">
                                            <%#Eval("O1") %>
                                        </label>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                    <div runat="server" id="O2Div" visible='<%#Eval("O2Vis") %>' class="radio">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="pull-right" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="O2" value="option2">
                                            <%#Eval("O2") %>
                                        </label>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                    <div runat="server" id="O3Div" visible='<%#Eval("O3Vis") %>' class="radio">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="pull-right" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="O3" value="option3">
                                            <%#Eval("O3") %>
                                        </label>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                    <div runat="server" id="O4Div" visible='<%#Eval("O4Vis") %>' class="radio">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="pull-right" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="O4" value="option4">
                                            <%#Eval("O4") %>
                                        </label>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="SubmitPollButton" runat="server" Text="ثبت نظر" OnClick="SubmitPollButton_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

and im using this code to access it:

```
protected void SubmitPollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl O1Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)SelectedPollGridView.Rows.FindControl("O1");
        if (O1Radio.Attributes["checked"] == "checked")
        {
            Response.Redirect("somewhere");
        }            

    }
```

but it doesn't work.
can any body help me?
in my gridview there is just one template field. does it means i have just one row and one cell?

thank you very much.

Comment: On what method you're trying to get the control?

Comment: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl O1Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)SelectedPollGridView.Rows[0].FindControl("O1");

Comment: Add `runat="server"` tag : `<input class="pull-right" runat="server" ...`

Comment: Yes, but, this code in which method are? The method is in the event submitPollButton_Click? if so you can get the sender.

Comment: <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="SubmitPollButton" runat="server" Text="ثبت نظر" OnClick="SubmitPollButton_Click" />

.
it's in last line of the template field

Comment: i edited the question. i added the SubmitPollButton_Click function to code.

Comment: i added runat="Server" but its not working yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the RowCommand event on the gridview since the button click event bubbles up to the gridview control.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowCommand="OnGridRowCommand" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn" 
                    CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ID") %>" 
                    Text="Click" CommandName="foo" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void OnGridRowCommand(object sender, GridViewEventArgs e)
{
    //e.CommandSource - reference to the button
    //e.CommandName - the command name, in this case foo
    //e.CommandArgument - use it to find which row the button click originated from


}
```

Now if you are trying to find your other controls do something like:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl O1Radio =
   (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)
      ((Button)e.CommandSource).Parent.FindControl("O1");
```

Comment: I'm new to asp.net. thank you very much for your answer. I think i have to try on this couple of hours to get the answer.

Comment: what about if i want to use auto postback for radio buttons and remove the button?
thank you very much

Comment: @afzalulh my bad fixed it

Comment: I tested this but it says commandSource has not a property called Parent

Comment: I think i didnt underestand the code behind part. that comments in OnGridRowCommand. sorry im new to asp.

Comment: CommandSource property is of type object. So you need to cast it to Control. It will have the reference of the button you've clicked in the UI. I'll edit the code...

Comment: I used  `CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'` for my button and it gives the index of the row that button has clicked. is it correct?

Comment: may you watch this post? i edited the code and the problem solved. but there is another problem now.
[how to check which radio button is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323615/how-to-find-checked-radio-button-in-a-gridview)

Comment: If you traverse up the Control tree using `Control.Parent.Parent... ...etc` you will eventually find the reference to the grid view row object. (You just have to break the code in debugging mode and use the immediate window to find out).`CommandArgument` is used to tag any data related item, like for e.g., if my grid is binding to a northwind customer table, then I'd tag the CustomerID to the CommandArgument, so in code I know which Customer I have to act on...hope you get the sense.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention and effort :) 
best regards