# how to find checked radio button in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

how to find checked radio button?
there is a hatml input with type of radio and has 4 options to select called o1 o2 o3 and o4.
i can access the radio buttons with no problem.
how should i check which option is selected?

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="SelectedPollGridView_RowCommand" ID="SelectedPollGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PollID" DataSourceID="SelectedPollSqlDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <p runat="server" id="HeaderPTag" class="text-center"><small><%#Eval("Header") %></small></p>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p runat="server" id="BodyPTag" class="text-right"><%#Eval("Body") %></p>
                <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="PollIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PollID") %>'></asp:Label>

                <div runat="server" id="MainDiv">
                    <div runat="server" id="O1Div">
                        <label runat="server" id="O1Label">
                            <input runat="server" type="radio" name="OptionsOne" id="O1" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>'>
                            <%#Eval("O1") %>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div runat="server" id="O2Div">
                        <label runat="server" id="O2Label">
                            <input runat="server" class="pull-right" type="radio" name="OptionsTwo" id="O2" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>'>
                            <%#Eval("O2") %>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div runat="server" id="O3Div">
                        <label runat="server" id="O3Label">
                            <input runat="server" class="pull-right" type="radio" name="OptionsThree" id="O3" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>'>
                            <%#Eval("O3") %>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div runat="server" id="O4Div">
                        <label runat="server" id="O4Label">
                            <input runat="server" class="pull-right" type="radio" name="OptionsFour" id="O4" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>'>
                            <%#Eval("O4") %>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="foo" CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="SubmitPollButton" runat="server" Text="ثبت نظر" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SelectedPollSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GUOTSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [PollID], [Header], [Body], [O1], [O1Vis], [O2], [O2Vis], [O3], [O1Cnt], [O2Cnt], [O3Cnt], [O3Vis], [O4], [O4Cnt], [O4Vis], [PollDate] FROM [Poll] ">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PollID" QueryStringField="PollID" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and im using this code to access it:

```
protected void SelectedPollGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.CommandName == "foo")
    {
        // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
        // property to an Integer.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
        // by the user from the Rows collection.      
        GridViewRow row = SelectedPollGridView.Rows[index];

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O1Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O1");
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O2Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O2");
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O3Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O3");
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O4Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O4");
        Label myPollIDLAbel = (Label)row.FindControl("PollIDLabel");
    }
}
```

now how should i check which radio button has selected?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HtmlInputRadioButton** has a properties names `Checked` (return boolean type), you could use this prop. to check which radio button has selected.

For sample, after you get the radio button control in RowCommand event handler, then you have to check the prop. like this:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O1Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O1");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O2Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O2");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O3Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O3");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton O4Radio = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)row.FindControl("O4");

if(O1Radio.Checked)
{
  //O1Radio is selected.
} 
else if(O2Radio.Checked)
{
  //O2Radio is selected.
}
else if(O3Radio.Checked)
{
  //O3Radio is selected.
}
else if(O4Radio.Checked)
{
  //O4Radio is selected.
}
```

**EDIT**

To group radiobuttons, you should set the same name for all radiobuttons in a group:

```
...
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="Options" id="O1" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>' />
...
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="Options" id="O2" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>' />
...
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="Options" id="O3" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>' />
...
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="Options" id="O4" value='<%#Eval("PollID") %>' />
...
```

Comment: thank you. but it does not work since all radio buttons are Checked==true by default. this means O1Radio.Checked is always true even when i click on another radio options.

Comment: That because you set different **name** for each radiobutton, please see the editted answer.

Comment: may you take a look here?
thankyou very much again :)
[changing css of controls in gridview separately for each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326981/changing-css-of-controls-in-gridview-separately-for-each-row)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but **rusmus** answer should work fine, did you try his method?

Comment: as a matter of fact I ignored this method and used four button instead of radio button list and used four command name for each of buttons
you can check it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326981/changing-css-of-controls-in-gridview-separately-for-each-row)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar kind of situation some time back, that i solved using the below logic.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count; i++) //Check if item is selected  
        {
          if (((CheckBox)myGrid.Rows[i].FindControl(cbname)).Checked) //If selected            
            {
                .... //Magic Happens
            }
        }
```

So all the rows have checkbox in the grid, and the loop iterates through all the data and checks if the row is selected. Hope it helps :)

Khizer Jalal

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. but there is radio list button in the gridview and its a html 5 input control.
the first answer solved the problem. thank you again :)